Ok to use rear struts from junkyard?
They look in  pretty good shape, but not sure if its a good idea.
2005 Scion tC, 145 k miles.

Is the 145k figure from your car or the one in the junkyard?

My car, not junkyard car.

Which begs the question ... How many miles on the struts you're looking at?
